# How to change default suffix in filenames of georeferenced images

Tags: georeferencing

We would like to change the default suffix, which is appended to the file name when specifying transformation settings in the Georeferencer.
Is it possible to change this in the settings somewhere?

Background information: In the German QGIS Version it appends "_modifiziert", while in the English QGIS-Version it appends "_modified".
We use different language versions in our team, but would like to configure the Georeferencer so everyone saves georeferenced images with the same suffix in order to avoid having multiple georeferenced images of the same image with different file names.

[image]